wine errormessage: x86_64-binfmt-P: /opt/wine-9.3/bin/wine-preloader: Unable to allocate 0x7d7d01e028a0 bytes of virtual address space
I Installed wine on my system but get the following errormessage : x86_64-binfmt-P: /opt/wine-9.3/bin/wine-preloader: Unable to allocate 0x7d7d01e028a0 bytes of virtual address space. I tried removing the ~/.wine folder as suggested by some fixes for other problems. I can't even run winecfg, because I get the same errormessage. I also tried running wine as root. I Also tried sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade but that didn't help.
Hope you guys have any suggestions as I'm new to the linux community
Edit: It's Ubutu Desktop 64-bit on a  Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5 it should be the newest release. I installed wine through "Pi-Apps" but I do not know what Pi-Apps uses to install wine. (probably apt-get install wine ) I have 4GB of Memory if that helps. Neofetch say the os is Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) aarch64

What Ubuntu product are you using on your raspberry pi??  Packages (esp. deb) are built for specific releases, and we currently don't know what you're asking about?  Is it Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Desktop? Ubuntu Server? or something else? and what release of that unstated product?

@guiverc It's Ubutu Desktop 64-bit on a  Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5 it should be the newest release. I installed wine through "Pi-Apps" but I do not know what Pi-Apps uses to install wine. (probably apt-get install wine ) I have 4GB of Memory if that helps. I dont know what you mean by Release but I think this is the info you want: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) aarch64

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   Debian is not Ubuntu

@guiverc wheres the difference between debian and ubuntu? aren't those two based on top of eacht other?

There are differences in focus; let alone just the major difference of timing.  Yes my current Ubuntu oracular system is very close to my Debian trixie box; but released versions of Debian are from odd years thus are most aligned to releases of Ubuntu from that year (ie. non-LTS; esp. 23.04 for Ubuntu and Debian 12) thus details are now EOL & outdated on Ubuntu). To treat them as identical will lead to problems; never ignore the rather significant differences between them.   Site rules don't allow it anyway; this is still a Stack Exchange site
